# React+WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, reactjs

Можно ли, если у меня есть фронт-енд на React.js, соединить его с WordPress и что мне для этого потребуется? Можете скинуть ссылку на источник, где можно об этом почитать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете использовать [Gatsby](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress). Сам сайт React построен с помощью Gatsby.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!А это считается костылем и натягивают ли на WP темы созданные с помощью React?